# Accessing the values in a pandas quantized grouped series

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

(I bet this is a stupid question, sorry!)

Here is some simple code replicating my problem:

```python
rand_series = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 99, size = 100))
rand_series.index.name = 'user_id'
rand_series_binned = pd.cut(rand_series, [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100])
rand_series_binned_grp = rand_series_binned.groupby(rand_series_binned)
rand_series_binned_sampled = rand_series_binned_grp.apply(lambda grp: grp.sample(1))
rand_series_binned_sampled
```

The result printed from that is

```
           user_id
(0, 10]    32           (0, 10]
(10, 20]   0           (10, 20]
(20, 30]   91          (20, 30]
(30, 40]   75          (30, 40]
(40, 50]   98          (40, 50]
(50, 100]  29         (50, 100]
dtype: category
Categories (6, interval[int64]): [(0, 10] < (10, 20] < (20, 30] < (30, 40] < (40, 50] < (50, 100]]
```

How do I access each element of this whatever-it-is?

Here's a list of the things I have tried. There are 6 rows, so I would expect to get the first thus

```python
rand_series_binned_sampled[0]
```

or

```python
rand_series_binned_sampled.iloc[0]
```

both give the result

```
Interval(0, 10, closed='right')
```

That isn't the result I expected: `32`. Or I can index right off the end, e.g.

```python
rand_series_binned_sampled[12]
```

gives

```
user_id
0    (10, 20]
dtype: category
Categories (6, interval[int64]): [(0, 10] < (10, 20] < (20, 30] < (30, 40] < 
(40, 50] < (50, 100]]
```

So it appears to be treating my indexes not as row indexes but as numbers to be put into the buckets. The following all produce errors

```python
rand_series_binned_sampled[2,'user_id']  # KeyError
rand_series_binned_sampled[2]['user_id']  # KeyError
rand_series_binned_sampled[2][0]  # KeyError
rand_series_binned_sampled[2,0]  # KeyError
rand_series_binned_sampled[2].loc('user_id')  # ValueError
```

I can look at the keys and values, but I do not understand the results

```python
rand_series_binned_sampled.values
```

gives

```
[(0, 10], (10, 20], (20, 30], (30, 40], (40, 50], (50, 100]]
Categories (6, interval[int64]): [(0, 10] < (10, 20] < (20, 30] < (30, 40] < (40, 50] < (50, 100]]
```

```python
rand_series_binned_sampled.keys
```

gives

```
<bound method Series.keys of            user_id
(0, 10]    32           (0, 10]
(10, 20]   0           (10, 20]
(20, 30]   91          (20, 30]
(30, 40]   75          (30, 40]
(40, 50]   98          (40, 50]
(50, 100]  29         (50, 100]
dtype: category
Categories (6, interval[int64]): [(0, 10] < (10, 20] < (20, 30] < (30, 40] < (40, 50] < (50, 100]]>
```

Finally this one gives a `TypeError`

```python
for key, value in rand_series_binned_sampled:
    print(f'key: {key} value: {value}')
```

I think that's enough failed examples to give some idea of the depth of my confusion. What do I have to do to iterate through this and get keys like `(0, 10]` with values like `32` or even just access those `user_id` values at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having issues because of the multiindex. One option is drop level 0 and use `zip` to create a dict:

```
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)

rand_series = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 99, size = 100))
rand_series.index.name = 'user_id'
rand_series_binned = pd.cut(rand_series, [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100])
rand_series_binned_grp = rand_series_binned.groupby(rand_series_binned)
rand_series_binned_sampled = rand_series_binned_grp.apply(lambda grp: grp.sample(1))

           user_id
(0, 10]    99           (0, 10]
(10, 20]   42          (10, 20]
(20, 30]   83          (20, 30]
(30, 40]   78          (30, 40]
(40, 50]   50          (40, 50]
(50, 100]  56         (50, 100]
dtype: category
Categories (6, interval[int64]): [(0, 10] < (10, 20] < (20, 30] < (30, 40] < (40, 50] < (50, 100]]
```

then, if you want a `dict`:

```
# reset_index and drop level 0
s_drop = rand_series_binned_sampled.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
# use zip with dict
d = dict(zip(s_drop.index, s_drop))

{42: Interval(10, 20, closed='right'),
 50: Interval(40, 50, closed='right'),
 56: Interval(50, 100, closed='right'),
 78: Interval(30, 40, closed='right'),
 83: Interval(20, 30, closed='right'),
 99: Interval(0, 10, closed='right')}

# access interval from user_id
d[78]
# Interval(30, 40, closed='right')
```

Or if you want to continue to use the series and want to access an interval for a `user_id`:

```
s_drop.loc[42]
# Interval(10, 20, closed='right')

# or use s_drop[42]
```

or you can use boolean indexing for an interval to get the `user_id`

```
s_drop[s_drop == pd.Interval(20,30)].index
# Int64Index([83], dtype='int64', name='user_id')
```

## update

You create a multiindex Series because of the `groupby` here `rand_series_binned_grp = rand_series_binned.groupby(rand_series_binned)`

```
type(rand_series_binned_sampled.index)
# pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex

type(s_drop.index)
# pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index
```

Comment: How would I have known from the output that I had a series with a multiindex?

Comment: @dumbledad you can do `rand_series_binned_sampled.index` which will return `MultiIndex(levels=[[(0, 10] . . .)` or do `type(rand_series_binned_sampled.index)` which will return `pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex`